# How to click on inneHTML String with Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am iterating throw a table  getting the rows:

```
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="noteTable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 20%" scope="col"></th>
                        <th style="width: 20%" scope="col">Title</th>
                        <th style="width: 60%" scope="col">Description</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr id="notes" th:each="note : ${notes}">
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-success" id="btn-edit-note"
                               th:onclick="showNoteModal([[${note.id}]],
                                [[${note.noteTitle}]], [[${note.noteDescription}]])">Edit</a>
                            <a th:href="@{|/home/delete-note/?title=${note.noteTitle}|}"
                               id="btn-delete-note" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                        <th scope="row" th:text="${note.noteTitle}"></th>
                        <td th:text="${note.noteDescription}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

With this code written below :

```
public void deleteNote(String title, String description) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    WebElement btnDeleteNote;

    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", tabNotes);
    WebElement homeWait = wait.until(webDriver ->
            webDriver.findElement(By.id("btn-delete-note")));
    for (WebElement note : notes) {
        String noteTitle = note.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        System.out.println(noteTitle);
        if (noteTitle.contains(title)) {
            js.executeScript("DELETE NOTE HERE);
        }
    }
}
```

When I get the row innerHTML I receive this result as String :

```
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-success" id="btn-edit-note" onclick="showNoteModal(1,
        &quot;Note Title Test&quot;, &quot;Note Description Test&quot;)">Edit</a>
    <a href="/home/delete-note/?title=Note Title Test" id="btn-delete-note" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
</td>
<th scope="row">Note Title Test</th>
<td>Note Description Test</td>
```

#### - My question is: Thinking that the lines of a Table are Dynamic, how can I click on "< a >" tag element in the string row?

Comment: Why are you using JS to click elements instead of Selenium? Just try btnDeleteNote.click()

Comment: I faced a problem with WebElement.click() which the element was not found due to rendering time. JavascriptExecutor solved that problem. And another problem is that the element is in a row dynamically filled in a table, so in times it may exist e not in another, and also in the major of time it will be more than one button "deleteNote". So my problem is how to specifically click in one deleteNote instead of the others?

Comment: @Mick That is the problem: how can I find the btnDelete. btnDelete in my code was only an example. That was exactly what I'm trying to find from the innerHTML String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element has to be unique because it has an id so you can just target it like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("btn-delete-note")
print(element.text)
```

Comment: But the element is in a table width dynamic rows, so if I call by Id which one will be called?

Comment: @Henrique There can only be 1 element on the page with this ID, if you need to access various elements by row, you can findElements(By.className("btn.btn-danger")) and access the correct element with deleteButtons.get( index ).click(). If you can't map a specific index to the correct row, then you can try targeting the child button of each note with note.findElement( By id or class).click()